# How to NSFetchedResultsController coding in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode6

can't figure out how to rewrite the following method in **swift**
for a better learning curve, so i tried to translate this code.  so lets select a more difficult method to do so. it has `error handling`, `object init` and `parameter settings`, an `array of object pointers`, `selectors`, `nil`, and `self`..

Objective-C:

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *frC = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
        initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext 
        sectionNameKeyPath:nil 
        cacheName:@"Master"];
    frC.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = frC;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

specially can't figure out how to call `NSEntityDescription *entity`.
while interpreting the specs i could not rewrite this correct..

swift:

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {

    var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil  //??

    var fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest? = nil  // ??
    var entity: NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription( /*. . .*/ ) //??

    fetchRequest.entity(entity) //?? sure this is wrong

    ...

    return _fetchedResultsController
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like the code you get when you set up a master-detail project with CoreData.

You can do the same, in Xcode 6, but choosing Swift as the language. In MasterViewController, you get :

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Event", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)
    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: false)
    let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "Master")
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !_fetchedResultsController!.performFetch(&error) {
         // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
         // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
         //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
         abort()
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController!
}    
var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil
```

This looks like a line-to-line translation, I hope it helps.

Comment: I don't get it, weren't we supposed to drop instance variables with Swift? How are those two variables handled? What is the meaning of the very last line in this context?

Comment: The last line indeed acts like an instance variable. Strangely enough, if you look at the Core Data code template in the AppDelegate.swift file, you can see that Apple uses the same technique in multiple places, i.e. _instanceVariable.

Comment: Yes, you are right @iMaddin, but really I am not getting how this works, I am watching all WWDC Swift videos but I don't see this technique mentioned...

Answer (score 5):

try lazy:

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Event", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext())
    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: false)
    let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext(), sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "Master")
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !aFetchedResultsController.performFetch(&error) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return aFetchedResultsController
}()
```